# I'm confused by pip installations

Tags: python, terminal, pip

I have recently begun having troubles using pip to install python packages. I have always used pip but never really understood how it actually works, my experience with it is basically limited to "pip install pkg".

Recently when trying to install openCV on my machine, I followed a few guides that involved changing paths etc. Since making these changes I have been having trouble using pip to install packages correctly.

Now when I run "pip3 install pkg", the install runs fine without any errors. When I try to import the module in python however, python cannot find the package. If I run "pip3 list" in the terminal I get a list of modules that is different to running help('modules') within python.

I think pip is installing the packages to a different location than my version of python is referencing when importing modules?

Is there a way I can change where pip installs to? What did it mean to change paths and how can I avoid this in the future?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should mention that running "python3 -m pip install pkg" installs the packages correctly.

Comment: You can try this, It's isolate your python packages with respect to each project https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: you probably have both python2 and python3 installed? Your `pip` call is invoking the python2 version

Comment: I do have python2 and python3 installed, however I am calling pip3 rather than pip when installing.

Comment: What were the "guides that involved changing paths" that you followed?

Comment: When you call `pip` then it will be loaded from a directory in your `PATH` environment variable - it is probably picking-up the wrong one.  Get the full path name of the `pip` you need and always use that, don't leave it to chance.  Personally I have a little script called `runpip` which does this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 2 versions of python installed, the best solution is to install and use [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/)

A Virtual Environment is a tool to keep all dependencies required by different projects and python versions in separate places. It solves the problem you mentioned and keeps your site-packages directory manageable.